# How to check if StorageMap is empty?

Tags: storage

I have created a simple storage map as follows and I just want to check if it's empty or not. I am comparing it with rust `HashMaps`, it has the is_empty() method to check. I intend to use this in the same pallet.

```
#[pallet::storage]
#[pallet::getter(fn check_storage_map)]
pub type SimpleStorageMap<T: Config> =
    StorageMap<_, Blake2_256, u32, u32, ValueQuery>;
```

I checked the `storage map` rust doc but could not find any function associated with it.
I am new to substrate any advice or help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There exists the [`CountedStorageMap`](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/7a09b82772b0597cdae224f4b124d660dda9e82b/frame/support/src/storage/types/counted_map.rs#L49) that keeps track of the count of elements in the map:

```
/// A wrapper around a `StorageMap` and a `StorageValue<Value=u32>` to keep track of how many items
/// are in a map, without needing to iterate all the values.
///
/// This storage item has additional storage read and write overhead when manipulating values
/// compared to a regular storage map.
///
/// For functions where we only add or remove a value, a single storage read is needed to check if
/// that value already exists. For mutate functions, two storage reads are used to check if the
/// value existed before and after the mutation.
///
/// Whenever the counter needs to be updated, an additional read and write occurs to update that
/// counter.
pub struct CountedStorageMap;
```

Answer (score 6):

You have multiple options to achieve your requirement. Eventually it boils down to checking for an empty iterator IMO.

You can retrieve two iterators of your StorageMap:

1. Either the `KeyPrefixIterator` by calling `SimpleStorageMap::<T>::iter_keys()`
2. Or the `PrefixIterator` by calling `SimpleStorageMap::<T>::iter_values()`

Then, you could just check whether the first element of your Iterator is `None` or whether the collection to an arbitrary vector is empty:

```rust
assert!(SimpleStorageMap::<T>::iter_keys().next().is_none());

assert!(SimpleStorageMap::<T>::iter_keys().collect::<Vec<_>>().is_empty());
```

Comment: `assert!(SimpleStorageMap::<T>::iter_keys().collect::<Vec<_>>().is_empty());`

That is a really bad idea, just assume you have some big map. Then it would lead to some huge amount of data being read. For a Parachain that would lead to a really huge `StorageProof`.

Comment: Thats true. Using a CountedStorageMap definitely is the best solution for the OP.

Comment: This does make sense, thanks.